# iReport - Dynamic images or image height

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

having an issue with iReport/JasperReports and not sure the best way to tackle it. The report is a typical order detail style report with each line item enumerated with attributes like quantity, description, name, price, etc.

However, the problem I would like to solve revolves around displaying optional pictures as part of the line item description. Each line item could have N number of detailed pictures - think of it as multiple images of a product (like under the car hood, the wheels, interior, exterior, etc). The number of images is displayed at run time.

How can I include these dynamic images? I could create placeholders for 9 images, and hide if they aren't passed in, but that would leave blank space for the line items that don't have that many images. I could even combine all of the misc images into one bigger image before I passed to the report, but I still have the sizing issue.

Can't seem to figure out how to have dynamic sizing on the band, while still allowing multiple optional images.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Here is an example. These is extra space on the other rows that should have been collapsed. Note, I only see this when I export to PDF. I don't see it in the internal viewer. That looks ok. [link](http://www.sherpasoftwaredevelopment.com/example.jpg)

Comment: Would it not be more accurate to say, "The number of images is determined at run time."?

Answer (score 2):

To solve your issue with blank space. You can set the band to not print when there is no data (would require 1 band for each picture/item. Or each component has a property 'Remove Line When Blank' which will compact the space if there is no data/images to show on that horizontal space.

Comment: There are several pictures horizontally, so one band per picture won't work. The Remove Line When Blank is checked, and the images do indeed not print, but the whitespace is still there. I should not that this is working correctly on the internal viewer, it's just when I export to PDF that the whitespace doesn't do away. The link I posted above demonstrate this.

Comment: Actually if I'm understanding your example correctly you should be using two extra bands below each detail item. 1 Band has images 1-4 and the second band has images 5-8. Write an expression that only shows the band if there is at least 1 image in it. So for Item #2 the 2nd image band would be hidden and for item #3 both image bands would be hidden.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I feel silly for not thinking about the multiple bands already. I did do this and it got me closer. The PDF export doesn't seem to like multiple PDF bands (the internal viewer is fine), so I had to go some funky grouping to accomplish the same thing. Not super graceful, but it's working. Not sure why you can't have multiple detail bands though.

Comment: Current versions of jasperreports do allow multiple detail bands. For older versions though - I think .... not quite sure. If you leave the group expression blank then it will essentially be another detail band. Otherwise you should be able to just have both groups on item# and they will both print after each item (essentially 2 more detail bands).

Comment: I'm on the 4.x series. Multiple detail bands look great in iReport's internal preview, but not when Jasper exports to PDF. It ignores all the detail bands except for the last.